# Является ли объект числом в Python 3 без использования модуля numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, методы

Как определить, является ли какой-то объект числом?

Есть известные методы `str().isdigit()` и `str().isnumeric()` для строк, но они уже не работает в случае комплексных чисел, или даже для вещественных.

Я нашел метод использующий модуль `numbers`, такой код:

```
import numbers


variable = 5
print(isinstance(5, numbers.Number))
```

Должен выдать `True`. Очевидным было бы просто сравнить тип объекта со всеми существующими типами чисел в питоне, но это кажется какой-то пушкой по воробьям.

Очень бы хотелось, чтобы код не использовал каких-то библиотек и был коротким, возможно есть какой-то метод, тем более это кажется весьма тривиальной задачей, на которую я уверен уже есть решение, но ссылку я не смог найти, буду благодарен за ссылку!

Comment: А вам нужны комплексные числа? А то можно напридумывать столько вариантов всяких чисел... Экспоненциальная форма вещественных чисел, например. Кажется, были готовые регулярные выражения, которые могут это всё, но какую задачу вы всё-таки решаете, хотелось бы знать?

Comment: А так то можно просто пытаться преобразовать во `float`, обернув в блок `try/except`, и этого для большинства случаев будет достаточно.

Comment: @CrazyElf Любой объект, который в стандартном `Python 3` есть число (Их очень много?). Думаю да, идея с `float` хорошая

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
>>> variable = 5
>>> 
>>> print(isinstance(variable, int))
True
```

---

```
>>> variable = 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1
>>> 
>>> variable
0.9999999999999999
>>> print(isinstance(variable, float))
True
```

Comment: Это проверка на то является ли объект целым числом, уже для вещественных не будет работать

Comment: @NeoFanatic во втором параметре функции `isinstance` можно в кортеже передать интересующие типы: `isinstance(variable, (int, float, complex))`